# Выбокра из БД user с его детьми бесконечно

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, первый раз сталкиваюсь с такой выборкой. Во общем есть такая таблица `user`

- `id` - идентификатор пользователя
- `name` - имя пользователя
- `parent_id` - ссылка на идентификатор родительской записи

Мне нужно вытащить из базы данных всех пользователей у кого `parent_id` равно `id` текущего пользоваеля.

Потом где `parent_id` равно ихние `id` и так бесконечна пока не закончится цепочка. Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Рекурсия, не? хорошие статьи на эту тему http://habrahabr.ru/post/46659/ http://habrahabr.ru/post/153861/

Comment: Если таблица не большая, то можно запихнуть все в массив и уже дергать из массива, чтобы не обращаться многократно к базе

Comment: Да, не большая, так и собираюсь делать)